# Using Git to manage two versions of a website

Tags: git

I'm sure this falls into the *Using Git For What It Is Not Intended* category, but I wanted to share what I am doing so that experts might comment on it.

I am using virtual hosting on my live server so that I can have 2 versions of my site running at once. One is example.com and the other is staging.example.com. The staging site is used for testing new features and I created a way to link two branches of the site's git repo (say, *staging* and *master*) to their respective site roots.

First of all, I set up git on the remote server so that I can checkout the latest master to the web root automatically when I push ([using this great technique](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)).

Then, in my post-receive hook I put this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www git checkout master -f
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/staging/site/webroot git checkout staging -f
```

With this method, I can keep two versions of the site going, using two branches in git), and when I push, the staging site gets updated with any new changes in the staging branch, and same with the master site.

I have found it to be a great way to manage demoing new features before making them public.

Should I not be doing this? Is there a better way? Other ideas or concerns?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Seems fine to me.  You could be slightly more clever in your hook: check the third argument for each input line (`while read old new ref; do ...`) and if it's `refs/heads/master` you need to update the live site, while if it's `refs/heads/staging` you need to update the staging site.  If it's anything else (some other branch, or a tag, or whatever), do nothing at all.  Note that you can get multiple updates at once: to refs/heads/{master,staging,make-zorg-more-evil} and also a half dozen new tags, for instance.

Comment: @torek, can you explain more specifically how to do that?

Comment: Too much to squeeze into a comment, but look at post-receive-email (e.g., `/usr/share/doc/git-1.7.4.4/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email`).  It's way over-complicated for this particular case but it shows how to do a very fancy post-receive hook.  I guess I can add an "answer" below....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted to know how to be fancier.  I'm going to go through the post-receive email hook script to show how it works (in part).  This gets pretty long! :-)

OK, so, here's the crucial bits from `post-receieve-email` (reformatted a bit):

```
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    prep_for_email $oldrev $newrev $refname || continue
    generate_email $maxlines | send_mail
done
```

This reads the old-SHA, new-SHA, and ref names from the input stream (I consider this one of git's failings: you can only read this stream once, then it's gone; this makes connecting up a bunch of otherwise unrelated hooks overly difficult) and invokes two shell functions to examine them and then either ignore, or do something with, each one.

Now here's the crucial bits from the `prep_for_email` shell function, with commentary:

```
prep_for_email()
{
    oldrev=$(git rev-parse $1)
    newrev=$(git rev-parse $2)
    refname="$3"
```

The rev-parse here (plus some code I dropped above that allows command-line arguments) allows you to feed the thing rev-names like "HEAD" and "HEAD^".  An actual post-receive hook always gets the raw SHA1, so the rev-parse calls are no-ops.

```
    # --- Interpret
    # 0000->1234 (create)
    # 1234->2345 (update)
    # 2345->0000 (delete)
    if expr "$oldrev" : '0*$' >/dev/null
    then
        change_type="create"
    else
        if expr "$newrev" : '0*$' >/dev/null
        then
            change_type="delete"
        else
            change_type="update"
        fi
    fi
```

In a post-receive hook, if the "old" SHA1 is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (all zeros, which is 40 0s; the `expr` above just checks for all-zeros), this means that the "ref" argument did not exist before, and now does.  That's typically a branch create op, but can also be a tag create.  On the other hand, if the "new" SHA1 is all zeros, the "ref" argument *did* exist before, and now doesn't: typically a branch delete op.  Anything else, the ref-name *used* to resolve to the old-rev and now resolves to the new-rev.  That's typically a branch update, but it can also be a tag move for instance.

Next, the email hook has some good "paranoia style" programming, cross-checking the ref-name against the actual underlying object type in the git repo:

```
    # --- Get the revision types
    newrev_type=$(git cat-file -t $newrev 2> /dev/null)
    oldrev_type=$(git cat-file -t "$oldrev" 2> /dev/null)
    case "$change_type" in
    create|update)
        rev="$newrev"
        rev_type="$newrev_type"
        ;;
    delete)
        rev="$oldrev"
        rev_type="$oldrev_type"
        ;;
    esac
```

If the ref-name has the form `refs/tags/*` and the update is to an annotated tag, this should set both `$oldrev_type` and `$newrev_type` to `tag`.  (If it's a lightweight tag these will both be `commit` instead.  If a lightweight tag turned into an annotated tag, the old type will be commit and the new type will be tag, and so on.)  And of course, if you're deleting a branch or a tag, the "new" rev will be all 0s and `$newrev_type` will be the empty string because `git cat-file -t` will simply fail (that's why the `2> /dev/null`).

(Aside: there's no good reason one `git cat-file -t` has its argument quoted, and one doesn't.  Probably just someone got overly happy with quoting after running into the usual empty-string argument issues, but missed one.  Fortunately it's harmless either way in this case. :-) )

The email script then has a very long `case` statement:

```
case "$refname","$rev_type" in
    ...
esac
```

which makes sure that an operation on `refs/heads/*` is always a `commit`.  If not, it prints a message to stderr (which, on a `git push`, will be sent to whoever did the push, prefixed with `remote:`, so that *someone* can see it):

```
    refs/heads/*,commit)
        # branch
        refname_type="branch"
        short_refname=${refname##refs/heads/}
        ;;
    ...
    *)
        # Anything else (is there anything else?)
        echo >&2 "*** Unknown type of update to $refname ($rev_type)"
        echo >&2 "***  - no email generated"
        return 1
        ;;
```

Now for the useful bits from `generate_email`.  Look at the actual script for details, but, in this case we only really care about the call to `generate_email_header`, plus the case that invokes `generate_update_branch_email`.

Here's the header:

```
generate_email_header()
{
    # --- Email (all stdout will be the email)
    # Generate header
    cat <<-EOF
    To: $recipients
    Subject: ${emailprefix}$projectdesc $refname_type $short_refname ${change_type}d. $describe
    X-Git-Refname: $refname
    X-Git-Reftype: $refname_type
    X-Git-Oldrev: $oldrev
    X-Git-Newrev: $newrev

    This is an automated email from the git hooks/post-receive script. It was
    generated because a ref change was pushed to the repository containing
    the project "$projectdesc".

    The $refname_type, $short_refname has been ${change_type}d
    EOF
}
```

`$change_type`, in the case we care about, is `update` so this says things like: `branch zorg updated.`  (`$describe` is the output from `git describe $newrev`, or if that's empty—i.e., there were no annotated tags for `git describe` to use—just `$newrev`.  `$recipients`, `$emailprefix`, and `$projectdesc` are from various configurables.)

In `generate_update_branch_email`, there's a whole lot of stuff to compute and print-for-emailing exactly *which* commits were removed and added; and then it ends with:

```
    echo "Summary of changes:"
    git diff-tree --stat --summary --find-copies-harder $oldrev..$newrev
```

Basically, a branch reference `$refname` of the form `refs/heads/*` (say, `refs/heads/zorg`), that has been `update`d (from an existing `$oldrev` that was not all 0s, to a new `$newrev` that is not all 0s), means that said (long-form) branch name, which people normally refer to as `$short_refname` (`zorg`), has moved that branch tip.  Which is a whole lot simpler than is the code to figure out exactly what that move *means*!

In your case, you don't need to worry about branch creation; you can treat that like a regular update.  You might (or might not) want to do something special on branch deletion.  Most of the time you only care about branch updates ... and all you want to do is, if `staging` has been updated, update your special staging copy; if `master` has been updated, update your special `master` copy.  In each case, the update will be "to the new branch tip", which is really easy to access.

So, if we put all this together, we get the following (untested, but pretty trivial) hook, to which I've added the ability to invoke it from the command line.  To make it more useful, when invoked from the command line, you can specify the revision you want checked-out wherever it goes, e.g., you can say `./hookscript unused master~2 refs/heads/staging` to shove rev `master~2` into the staging copy area (assuming you wanted to do that for some reason).

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# handle updates to our two interesting branches, staging and master.

# function to dump given commit state to target directory
# arguments: $1 - rev; $2 - target dir
copy_to_dir() {
    GIT_WORK_TREE="$2" git checkout -q -f "$1"
}

# function to handle an update to staging branch.
# arguments: $1 - rev to check out
update_staging() {
    copy_to_dir $1 /path/to/staging/site/webroot
}

# function to handle an update to master branch.
update_master() {
    copy_to_dir $1 /var/www
}

# function to handle one reference-change.
# arguments:
#    $1 - old revision, or all-0s on create
#    $2 - new revision, or all-0s on removal
#    $3 - reference (refs/heads/*, refs/tags/*, etc)
refchange() {
    local oldrev="$1" newrev="$2" ref="$3"
    local deleted=false
    local short_revname

    if expr "$newrev" : '0*$' >/dev/null; then
        deleted=true
    elif ! git rev-parse "$newrev"; then
        return # git rev-parse already printed an error
    fi

    case $ref in
    refs/heads/staging|refs/heads/master)
        shortref=${refname#refs/heads/};;
    *)
        return;;
    esac

    # someone pushed a change to staging branch or master branch
    if $deleted; then {
        echo "WARNING: you've deleted branch $shortref"
        echo "are you sure you wanted to do that?"
        echo "The operating copy is still operating, and"
        echo "will be updated when the branch is re-created."
        } 1>&2
        return
    fi

    # update either the staging copy or the master copy
    update_$shortref "$newrev"
}

# main driver: update from input stream (if no arguments) or use arguments
case $# in
3)  refchange "$1" "$2" "$3";;
0)  while read oldrev newrev refname; do
        refchange $oldrev $newrev $refname
    done;;
*)  echo "ERROR: update hook called with $# arguments, expected 0 or 3" 1>&2;;
esac
```

Note, because I'm using `git checkout -q -f` on a parsed rev (rather than a name like `staging` or `master`), this will take the pushed-to branch to "detached HEAD" state each time.  More importantly, if you use the command-line trick from a "normal" repo on the web server, it will unmoor your current branch.  This is not fatal but could easily be annoying.  To avoid that, replace the contents of `copy_to_dir` with, e.g., `git archive $1 | (rm -rf "$2" && mkdir "$2" && cd "$2" && tar xf -)`.

(Normally you'd be pushing to a `--bare` repo, and changing its idea of "current branch" is not a problem, since nobody cares about that.)

Comment: this works great. you have a lot of good error checking, which i have not tested, but it does what i want and it is very clean. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, you're using Git in a way that Git should be used for. You have two versions of the same files and you want to maintain each "version" separately, as a branch.

I assume that when you're ready to merge the changes from staging to master you simply do something like `git merge staging`/`git rebase staging` inside the `master` branch and go from there.

You're not using Git wrong at all.

Comment: that's exactly what I do and it works great. I do agree with torek that it would be better to only checkout branches that have been updated, but I could use a little more explanation on how to do that.